# Class syntax on dependent type

Tags: haskell

Recently I tried implementing linear maps class for 2d vectors.
It was fine until I tried to change the base type (base-ring) of vectors to a generic one.
I have the following type for vectors:

```
data Vector a = V a a
```

(As far as I know, I can't or shouldn't specify what `a` is.)

And I want to have a class (not a type) for linear maps.
The reason behind it: I want to have a very specific linear maps, say rotations, that depends on a different set of parameters (and may even not depend on any params, for example x-reflection have no params), but they all have one purpose -- apply to vector (that is why I call it a class).

I tried defining the following class

```
class LinearMap m where
  apply :: m -> Vector a -> Vector a
```

And say I want two instances

```
data Rotation a = Rot a

instance LinearMap (Rotation a) where
  Rot phi `apply` V x y = V (c * x - s * y) (s * x + c * y)
    where
      (c, s) = (cos phi, sin phi)
```

but it gives me an error, because I expected a type

```
apply :: Rotation a -> Vector a -> Vector a
```

while compiler expected

```
apply :: Rotation a -> Vector b -> Vector b
```

And even if type binding is not a problem as in the following

```
data Reflection = XRefl | YRefl

instance LinearMap Reflection where
  XRefl `apply` V x y = V (-x) y
  YRefl `apply` V x y = V x (-y)
```

I get an error, because now `x` and `y` must be instances of `Num`,
but I don't see where I should write the instance.

An easy option would be to edit the `LinearMap` class and add something like

```
class LinearMap m where
  apply :: Num a => m -> Vector a -> Vector a
```

but it is not what I was trying to do (I hope you see my motivation),
and it doesn't solve the `Rotation` problem, either.

UPD: Here is what I came up with (not quite happy)

```
class LinearMap m a | m -> a where
  apply :: m -> Vector a -> Vector a
```

Now `Rotation` is fine:

```
instance Floating a => LinearMap (Rotation a) a where
  -- apply = ...
```

But `Reflection` needs an update

```
data Reflection a = XRefl | YRefl
```

so I can define an instance

```
instance Num a => LinearMap (Reflection a) a where
  -- apply = ...
```

Because `a` *depends* on `m` as in `LinearMap` class definition.
But now I'm not happy that `Reflection` depends on something (it shouldn't right?).

Comment: Do you really need the functional dependency?

Comment: The vector space is defined on top of a base field (or if you prefer a module is defined on top of a base ring) and those always have additive inverse. But in Haskell, the unary minus function is restricted to `Num`, so if you use it, your base ring/field is automatically restricted to `Num`.

Answer (score 1):

## Approach 1: using type families and constraints

This is probably not the most elegant approach, yet... one way to do it is to add in the class a *dependent constraint* on the `a` type you use in `Vector a`.

Here's the class:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.Kind

data Vector a = V a a

class LinearMap m where
  type CMap m (a :: Type) :: Constraint
  apply :: CMap m a => m -> Vector a -> Vector a
```

Here, `CMap m a` is a constraint defining what's needed for `apply` to work.

```
data Rotation a = Rot a

instance LinearMap (Rotation a) where
  type CMap (Rotation a) a' = (Floating a, a ~ a')
  Rot phi `apply` V x y = V (c * x - s * y) (s * x + c * y)
    where
      (c, s) = (cos phi, sin phi)
```

For `Rotation a`, we need `a` to be the same `a` in `Vector a`, so we require the type equality `a ~ a'`. We also require `Floating` so that `cos` can be used.

```
data Reflection = XRefl | YRefl

instance LinearMap Reflection where
  type CMap Reflection a' = (Num a')
  XRefl `apply` V x y = V (-x) y
  YRefl `apply` V x y = V x (-y)
```

For `Rotation`, we only require `Num`. Any numeric `a'` is allowed.

## Approach 2: just remove the fundep (?)

I now wonder if it would be better to use both arguments in the type class, as in `LinearMap m a` and move the constraints to the instances. We just avoid the fundep `m -> a`.

```
class LinearMap m a where
  apply :: m -> Vector a -> Vector a

data Rotation a = Rot a

instance Floating a => LinearMap (Rotation a) a where
  Rot phi `apply` V x y = V (c * x - s * y) (s * x + c * y)
    where
      (c, s) = (cos phi, sin phi)

data Reflection = XRefl | YRefl

instance Num a => LinearMap Reflection a where
  XRefl `apply` V x y = V (-x) y
  YRefl `apply` V x y = V x (-y)
```

Is there anything wrong with this simpler approach I missed? We don't get `a` inferred from `Rotation a` during type inference since we lack the fundep. Is that a real issue?

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I know, I can't or shouldn't specify what `a` is

You absolutely *can* specify what `a` is. Whether you *should* is a different matter. Most of the Haskell community uses the [`linear`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear) package, which does indeed leave the scalar type fully polymorphic. IMO this makes little sense, because only very few types make sense in practice as scalars, and it is *not* sensible for vector types to be fully parametric functors (because conceptually, the choice of basis is arbitrary but fmapping a nonlinear function destroys the symmetry).

So [what I advocate for](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linearmap-category) is actually to use *monomorphic* vector types, or at least treat them as monomorphic:

```
data Vector2D a = Vector2D a a

type ℝ² = Vector2D Double
```

Likewise, a given linear-map instance will be specific to one concrete vector type. There are two ways of expressing this:

- With an associated type family. In fact you maybe want two, for the domain and codomain:

  ```
   class LinearMapTF m where
     type LinMapDomain m :: Type
     type LinMapCodomain m :: Type
     apply :: m -> LinMapDomain m -> LinMapCodomain m
  ```

  This is IMO the clearest, but it means every linearmap-type will have one particular domain and codomain, and in particular you can't have `Reflection` act on different-typed domains. It's the same issue you get with your functional dependency.
- As a multi-param typeclass. You already had this in the original, but I would remove the scalar type from the interface in favour of abstract vector spaces, and also remove the functional dependency if you want to allow some kinds of linear maps to act on different spaces. Sticking to the specific case of endomorphisms, it's simply

  ```
   class LinearMapMP m v where
     apply :: m -> v -> v
  ```

Despite the treatment of vector spaces as non-parametric entities, you can in both cases perfectly well swap out scalar types. `Rotation` can still

```
data Rotation a = Rot a

instance LinearMapTF (Rotation a) where
  type LinMapDomain (Rotation a) = Vector2D a
  type LinMapCodomain (Rotation a) = Vector2D a
  Rot phi `apply` V x y = ...

instance a~b => LinearMapMP (Rotation a) (Vector2D b) where
  Rot phi `apply` V x y = ...
```

In this example, both approaches are basically equivalent. In case of reflection, they're different:

```
data ReflectionFxd a = XRefl | YRefl

instance LinearMapTF (ReflectionFxd a) where
  type LinMapDomain (ReflectionFxd a) = Vector2D a
  type LinMapCodomain (ReflectionFxd a) = Vector2D a
  apply = ...

data ReflectionArb = XRefl | YRefl

instance LinearMapMP ReflectionArb (Vector2D a) where
  apply = ...
```

---

Side note: none of what you're asking about really has to do with linear mappings. Your examples are actually specific cases of *groups acting on manifolds*. It makes a lot of sense to use rotations on spheres, for example. This is another motivation not to use scalar-parametric vector types but instead abstract types representing topological spaces. I also [have a package going in that direction](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/manifolds).